# A more time efficient way to multiply two polynomials (with singly linked lists)?

Tags: java, list

I have a Java problem. I'm writing a method to multiply two polynomials (stored as single-linked lists of terms). I already have methods for multiplying a term into a polynomial, and adding two polynomials together.

In my current solution, I create two polynomial objects, and then in a for-each loop, I make the *temp* object equal to a deep clone of *p1* (earlier, I was just setting *temp* to be equal to *p1*, which I realize now changes *p1* for every change of *temp*).

Then, I multiply the current term of *p2* with temp, and add the resulting polynomial to a placeholder object *multiplyPoly*.

Currently, I think this is running at O(n^3). Is there a way I can do this more efficiently, maybe without having to create a copy of *p1*?

```
 public static Polynomial multiply(Polynomial p1, Polynomial p2)
 {
  Polynomial multiplyPoly = new Polynomial();
  Polynomial temp = new Polynomial();


  for (Term y : p2.polynomial) {
   temp.polynomial = p1.polynomial.deepClone();
   temp.multiplyTerm(y);
    multiplyPoly = Polynomial.add(multiplyPoly,temp);
   }
   return multiplyPoly;
 }
```

Comment: Why does a Polynomial have a field called polynomial?

Comment: In order to get rid of the cloning you could explicitly loop over all terms with nested for loops. This won't improve runtime though, assuming your `add` and `multiplyTerm` have linear runtime your program is already in O(n^2). How do you conclude its O(n^3)?

Comment: There's a speed tester I'm using, the output of that made it seem like it was above O(n^2). Wouldn't the deepClone make it O(n^3)?